# show a bold font in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a textarea and I put in a word or words in bold
es.  Eat 
and then view the frmattato can you tell me how to make mvc asp.nt?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question is almost incoherent, I'm afraid. I'm *guessing* you want to be able to have the facility to entered formatted text into a textarea? In that case you require what is known as a 'WYSIWYG' HTML Editor (What You See is What You Get).

A list of ten of the most popular ones [can be found here.](http://qeqnes.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/)

In future, please try and word your questions so they are more understandable. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for being able to work that out, whether it was the right answer or not, I don't know.